# Filter generic list (comma separated values)

Tags: linq, generic-list

I want to filter list as below. I have a class & I want to filter values from that are in my filter string. I have achieved my result by a for loop but need a way without for loop.

```
Public Class WorkStationDetails<br><br>
    Property CountryId As Integer<br>
    Property CountryName As String<br>
    Property TotalWrkStn As Integer<br>
    Property ExistingWrkStn As Integer<br>
    Property RemainingWrkStn As Integer<br><br>
End Class

Dim WrkStnDtl As List(Of WorkStationDetails)
Dim FilterWrkStnDtl As List(Of WorkStationDetails)
Dim Numbers As String()

Numbers = "1,5,6,2,9".Split(",")

  For i As Integer = 0 To Numbers.Length - 1
      FilterWrkStnDtl.AddRange(WrkStnDtl.FindAll(Function(p) (p.CountryId = Numbers(i))))
  Next
```

**Note: I want to achieve it like subquery in sql server.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this"

```
var numbers = "1,5,6,2,9".Split(',');
var selected = WrkStnDtl.Where(w => numbers.Contains(w.CountryId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Ya, by I write like var numbers = "10".Split(",") and in country there is 1 so I will work?

Comment: Yes, that will work.  You need to change the double quotes to single around the comma.  "10".Split(',')